# Microsoft Word VBA to insert footer from excel

Tags: vba, ms-word, footer

Am trying to insert footer in Word Document from Excel (VBA). I want the footer to be like this:

`Footer Left                                                        Right Footer:`
`CustomText                                                           Page 1 of 5`

Below is the vba code written in excel:

```
Sub FooterTextwithpageNum()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim FooterTemp As Object
    
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set FooterTemp = objWord.ActiveDocument 
  
    FooterTemp.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.Text = "This is Custom Text"

    FooterTemp.Sections(1).Footers(1).PageNumbers.Add FirstPage:=True
End Sub
```

After the code executes am getting result as below:

`Footer Left                                                                  Right Footer:`
`This is Custom Text                                                                      1`

Instead of getting page numbers as Page X of Y its just numerals 1,2 etc. Can anybody please help me in getting page numbers as Page X of Y? Like below image:

[image]

Comment: why negative vote?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this link:  [How Can I Add a Page X of Y Footer to a Microsoft Word Document?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2007/06/06/how-can-i-add-a-page-x-of-y-footer-to-a-microsoft-word-document/)

I didn't look at it enough to figure out how to add your custom text as well but the code below is adapted to your sub from the link and does insert Page X of Y.

```
Sub FooterTextwithpageNum()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim FooterTemp As Object
    Dim objTemplate As Object
    Dim objRange As Object

    Set objWord = GetObject("", "Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
    Set FooterTemp = objWord.ActiveDocument

    Set objTemplate = objDoc.AttachedTemplate
    Set objRange = FooterTemp.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range

    objTemplate.AutoTextEntries("Page X of Y").Insert objRange

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Garth,
Thanks for the prompt response. I tried the code you posted and am getting `run-time error 5941`. Before posting this question on the stack overflow I tried searching for options over the internet and couldn't find any solutions closer to the one am looking for. It either inserts custom text or the page numbers but not both. I would like to know how can I add some text on left side of footer and Page X of Y on the right side of footer on the word document which is already open.

Comment: Added screenshot of how the footer should look on the main post

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work using Word's built in tab stops: `.InsertAfter vbTab`

Put it twice to have a left & right footer.

Entire Excel VBA footer code:

```
    ' FOOTER
    With wrdDoc.sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        .InsertAfter Text:="Printed: "
        .Fields.Add .Characters.Last, wdFieldEmpty, "DATE \@ ""MM/DD//YYYY""", False
        .InsertAfter vbTab
        .InsertAfter vbTab
        .InsertAfter Text:="Page "
        .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False
        .InsertAfter Text:=" of "
        .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES", PreserveFormatting:=False
    End With
```

Result:

[image]
Using Office 2016 (Office 365).