# Add footers in Word From Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, header, footer

I`m trying to insert some text in a Word file from an Excel workbook using Vba. This is part of the code that I have:

```
        fileRow = Range("AE101").Value
        fileLocation = Range("AE" & filaActa).Value         
        Set WordDoc = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WordDoc.DisplayAlerts = False
        WordDoc.Visible = True
        Set WordApp = WordDoc.Documents.Open(Filename:=File, ReadOnly:=False)
```

This is the last code that i`ve tried to, but I keep getting the same Error:

```
With WordApp.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        .InsertAfter Text:="Printed: "
        .Fields.Add .Characters.Last, wdFieldEmpty, "This is a Footer", False
        .InsertAfter vbTab
        .InsertAfter vbTab
        .InsertAfter Text:="Page "
        .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False
        .InsertAfter Text:=" of "
        .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES", PreserveFormatting:=False
End With
```

When I run it, I get the Error; "Run-time error '5941' the requested member of the collection does not exist"

I`ve tried to do the same thing as in this two solutions:

[Microsoft Word VBA to insert footer from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882470/microsoft-word-vba-to-insert-footer-from-excel)

[Find and Replace footer text in Word with an Excel VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536409/find-and-replace-footer-text-in-word-with-an-excel-vba-macro)

But I can`t find the problem. What can I do? I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting a field and naming the field "This is a footer" for some reason. That is not going to work and generates an error message. [This is what the field codes look like and the first one is not a field and will generate an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPfD3.png)

```
With WordApp.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    .InsertAfter Text:="Printed: "
    .Fields.Add .Characters.Last, wdFieldEmpty, "PrintDate", False
    .InsertAfter vbTab
    .InsertAfter vbTab
    .InsertAfter Text:="Page "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False
    .InsertAfter Text:=" of "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES", PreserveFormatting:=False
End With
```

Instead of PrintDate you may want a simple Date field because the PrintDate will not be active until *after* the document has been printed. The Date field will normally update before printing. See [Using Date Fields in Microsoft Word](http://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm) for more information on the various date fields available and how to format them.

If this is a new document you are creating, this would better be done using a template that already has the footer you want.

Other options would include having an AutoText or Footer Building Block in a template and calling that. [Using vba to insert a building block](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock).

Comment: If you read the code in the question you will see that `WordApp` actually points to  a document. So `WordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range` will error.

Comment: Thank you Timothy, you are correct. I am amending the response so it does not mislead someone else.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't shown the variable declarations in your code it isn't clear whether you are using early or late binding. Given the examples you have linked to I am guessing you are using late binding.

When using late binding you cannot use the constants from the Word object library, i.e. `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` and `wdFieldEmpty`, as Excel doesn't know what those represent. You either have to declare those constants yourself or use their underlying values. This is likely to be what is causing your error.

You can avoid these errors by adding `Option Explicit` at the top of the code module. This will prevent your code from compiling when you have undeclared variables. To add this automatically open the VBE and go to Tools | Options. In the Options dialog ensure that Require Variable Declaration is checked.
[image]

Late binding also means that you have used your object variables the wrong way round as you have set `WordDoc = Application` and `WordApp = Document`. So your first block of code should be:

```
    fileRow = Range("AE101").Value
    fileLocation = Range("AE" & filaActa).Value         
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=File, ReadOnly:=False)
```

As Charles pointed out when inserting a field you need to use a valid field code. Borrowing from the first of the examples you link to, your code for adding the footer then needs to be:

```
Const wdHeaderFooterPrimary as Long = 1
Const wdFieldEmpty as Long = -1     
With WordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    .InsertAfter Text:="Printed: "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="DATE \@ ""MM/DD//YYYY""", PreserveFormatting:=False
    .InsertAfter vbTab
    .InsertAfter vbTab
    .InsertAfter Text:="Page "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False
    .InsertAfter Text:=" of "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES", PreserveFormatting:=False
End With
```